Gradient of $(X^-T)K(X^-T)$
Let K and X real, symmetric nxn matrices.
Which is the gradient of f(X) = (X^-T)K(X^-T)?
T denotes the transpose of the matrix.

Does anything in the matrix cookbook help? https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf
